# Very simple HTML / PHP form issue

Tags: php, html, css

Please understand I am very aware similar issues have been posted here before. I have tried everything to fix this. It is driving me insane. Everything works fine other than this one issue:

User fill out a contact form and submits. The form is then emailed to my server's email perfectly. However, the content of the email isn't there. Basically, it as if my variables are not storing any of the data. Please look at below screen shot.

[The email in the inbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZulx.png)

The image shows that the subject works fine and the to works fine but the following variables do not work:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$yourmessage = $_POST['yourmessage'];
```

Please see my HTML AND PHP CODE BELOW.

**PHP**

```
<?php

$to = 'HIDDEN.co.uk';
$subject = 'New message from customer';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$yourmessage = $_POST['yourmessage'];

$body = <<<EMAIL

Hello.
<br><br>
Name: $name. 
<br>
Telephone: $number.
<br><br>
$yourmessage

EMAIL;

$headers    = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers   .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers   .= 'From: ' .$email. "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
header("location:../../../.../index.html");

?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="glossary/js-blueprints/js-contact-form/js-contact-form.php./" method="post" id="contact-form" class="contact-form">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" autocomplete="off" id="name" placeholder="Full name">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                        <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="number" autocomplete="off" id="number" placeholder="Telephone number">
                        </div>
                        </div>                      

                        <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" autocomplete="off" id="email" placeholder="Email Address">
                        </div>
                        </div>  

                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control textarea" rows="3" name="yourmessage" id="yourmessage" placeholder="Your message..."></textarea>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn main-btn pull-right">Send a message</button>
                  </div>
                  </div>
               </form>
```

Thank you for taking your time to help such a newb like myself.

Lewis.

Comment: can you do echo print_r($_POST) so we can see the contents of the post array?

Comment: or it actually might be just print_r($_POST)

Comment: I added echo print_r($_POST) to the bottom of my PHP however it did not produce anything.

Comment: after Name you have given $name. can you do echo($name) there and see if it works

Comment: Remove (or comment out) the `header()` command so that your debugging output will show.

Comment: POST:
Array
(
    [name] => eee
    [number] => 333
    [email] => eee
    [yourmessage] => ee
)

so as you can see the variables are working just not being sent to the email... mmm ;/

Comment: Hm, ok the $_POST array looks populated. Try `var_dump($body);`.

Comment: Removing the headers worked! There must have been an issue with them. It has however, created another problem. The email is sent twice! One perfect and the other without the data. Do you know what is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your headers are formatted incorrectly. Also, your $body is formatted awfully. And for good measure, you need to parse the data trying to be emailed to you. IE, should a name and email be set? Does it matter if it's a validated email? Usually you want checks like that before just emailing yourself, or storing the data.

```
$body = "Hello.<br /><br />
Name: " . $name . "<br />
Telephone: " . $number . "<br /><br />
" . $yourmessage;

$headers    = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$headers   .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
$headers   .= "From: " . $email . "\r\n";
```

Comment: You have a syntax-error in your code. See the highlighting.

Comment: What's wrong with the OP's headers? I don't see the difference.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This didn't seem to fix my issue. Thank you. Do you suggest anything else?

Comment: I wrote it quick and forgot one quote. You can try it now. Also, the OP's headers had mismatched quotations for the text. Look at it again and you'll see why it's wrong.

Comment: Sorry to be dense.. how is that wrong? I see [no difference](http://codepad.org/kFqJihqT) between the header output from the OPs code and from your code. Just trying to nail down the actual problem here...

Comment: I have got it working now. However, it is sending more than one email and the emails it sends aren't populated with data. Only one is. So it works technically it just also sends one or two more emails that dont have any data in them. really annoying. thanks again.

Comment: You're right. There is no difference in physical output for the headers. The OP is however unnecessarily combining strings in his header. That's what I meant to say. As for sending multiple emails, the only way that would happen is if for some reason you've looped the mail function. Have you implanted validation of the inputs?